# Make pinging faster while looking for a Windows PC

Tags: performance, ip-address, batch

This code pings 1 time every IP while using TTL to identify if it's a Windows PC. If so, it outputs it. It's very slow, so is there any way to make it go faster (1-255 in 12 min)?

```
@echo off
echo running, it will take a long time to scan
(
  FOR /L %%N in (1 1 254) DO (
      FOR /f "tokens=1,3 delims=: " %%A IN ('ping -n 1 192.168.250.%%N ^| find "TTL=128"') DO ECHO %%B

  )
) >ip.txt

echo done
get_info.bat
```

Comment: What is in `get_info.bat`?

Comment: a bunch of `Wmic` commands, not so important, can post if interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to reduce the timeout interval with the -w option (milliseconds), but I don't know what is the minimum timeout that still gives reliable results.

You could try

```
ping -w 500 -n 1 192.168.250.%%N
```

Comment: Isnt the defult 1000. Would it improve it that much ?

Comment: @TmCookieMonster - On my machine, the default is 4000 (4 seconds), so yes, a value of 500 makes a big difference. You certainly can set the value as low as you want, but I'm not a networking guy, so I don't know what a reasonable amount of time is to wait for a response.

Comment: Every pc on the network is connectes via fiber, so 500 should be good enough. Well thanks for the input, im out travelig right now but i will test it on Wednesday next week.

Comment: @TmCookieMonster - Well heck, try 100 :-)

Comment: it worked like a charm ! went form 12 min to 2 min ! thanks